# how to select max of two columns and group it by station

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a simple table like this

```
 station    num     tim
   1        150    10
   1       200     222
   1       100     5000
   1       200     555
   2       100     500
   2       120     200
   3        1      2
```

The output desired is like this

```
station num     tim
   1    200     555
   2    120     200
   3    1       2
```

i wrote this code but for station=1 and num=200 return two rows

```
(SELECT a.station , a.num ,a.tim
FROM test.dbo.tst a
JOIN (
SELECT station, MAX(num) num
FROM test.dbo.tst
GROUP BY station
) b ON a.station = b.station and a.num=b.num ) order by station
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to number rows grouped by `station` and ordered by `num` and `tim` descending and then select the rows with number equal to 1.

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Stations (
   station int,
   num int,
   tim int
)
INSERT INTO #Stations
   (station, num, tim)
VALUES
   (1, 150, 10),
   (1, 200, 222),
   (1, 100, 5000),
   (1, 200, 555),
   (2, 100, 500),
   (2, 120, 200),
   (3, 1,   2)
```

Statement:

```
;WITH cte AS (   
   SELECT 
      station, 
      num, 
      tim,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY station ORDER BY num DESC, tim DESC) AS Rn
   FROM #Stations
)
SELECT 
   station, 
   num, 
   tim
FROM cte
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Output:

```
station num tim
1       200 555
2       120 200
3       1   2
```

Comment: Using Window function is better than using 2 GROUP BY clauses, i will leave to mention another possible method but you will get my upvote +1

Comment: Also i updated my answer and mentioned that to inform the OP to not accept my answer if he doesn't know that. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1**

The recommended method is the one mentioned by @Zhorov, but i will leave my answer to give all possible solutions

---

**Initial answer**

Try using a similar query:

```
SELECT T.station, T.maxnum, MAX(T.tim) as maxtim 
FROM (SELECT station, tim, MAX(num) as maxnum
      GROUP BY station, tim ) T
GROUP BY station, maxnum
```

OR

```
WITH CTE_1 as (SELECT station, tim, MAX(num) as maxnum
               GROUP BY station, tim)
SELECT station, maxnum, Max(tim)
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY station, tim
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) partition function, something along these lines should do the trick:

```
SELECT  [Station], [Num], [Tim]
FROM
(
    SELECT  Station,
            Num,
            Tim,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Station ORDER BY Num DESC, Tim DESC) [N]
    FROM    tst
) SQ
WHERE    [N] = 1
```

This works on the basis of taking each group of rows, as grouped by the `Station` column (this is what the `PARTITION BY` part of the `ROW_NUMBER()` statement refers to), then ordering them first by `Num` and then by `Tim` and assigning each row in the result set a row number. The outer query then takes only the first row of each group, i.e. for each value of `Station` it takes the one with the highest value for `Num` and `Tim`.